# Is there a way to access the GeoProcessing tools in QGIS, in code

Tags: qgis, python, geoprocessing

Is there a way to access the GeoProcessing tools in QGIS, in code? I want to find the Difference between two layers and make a new shapefile with the result.It can be manually done by selecting vector->GeoProcessing Tools->Difference. But how to do it in my code? (I use python)
Please help me to find a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using processing:

```
import processing
processing.runalg("qgis:difference","C:/Users/anita_000/Geodata/qgis_sample_data/shapefiles/alaska.shp","C:/Users/anita_000/Geodata/qgis_sample_data/shapefiles/lakes.shp",None)
```

Comment: Difference in geoProcessing not working for some layers. It creates a new shapefile but not the expected result. (sometimes the same layer as input, or somtimes nothing) why is that?

Comment: That's a different question but most likely it's a CRS issue.

Comment: Sorry for asking a diffrent question. But I changed the crs by going to properties of the layers and select same crs for both. Then they didn't appear together or sometimes nothing shows. So is that mean, I need to load two layers which are originally in same crs?